# In/Out vs Out in Ada

Tags: ada

I have a quick Ada question.  If I have a procedure where I *may* write out to a variable, or I *might* leave it alone, should it be an `Out` parameter or an `In Out` parameter? I guess this boils down to the question:

What does the caller see if it calls a procedure with a parameter as `Out` but the procedure doesn't touch the parameter.  Does it see the same value? Undefined behavior?

The compiler doesn't complain because it sees an assignment to the `Out` variable...it just happens to be in a conditional, where it may not be reached, and the compiler doesn't bother to check all paths.

I suspect the safe bet is marking the parameter as `In Out`, but I'd like to know if this is necessary or just stylistically preferable.

Thanks!

-prelic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Ada, when a procedure with an `out` parameter does not write anything to that parameter, the result passed back to the caller is something *undefined*. This means that whatever was in that variable in the caller, gets overwritten by garbage on return from the procedure.

The best practice in Ada is to definitively initialise all `out` parameters with a suitable default value at the start of the procedure. That way, any code path out of the procedure results in valid data passed back to the caller.

If you have something in the caller that *might* be changed by a procedure, you must use an `in out` parameter.

From the [Ada 95 RM 6.4.1 (15)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-6-4-1.html):

> For any other type, the formal parameter is uninitialized. If composite, a view conversion of the actual parameter to the nominal subtype of the formal is evaluated (which might raise Constraint_Error), and the actual subtype of the formal is that of the view conversion. If elementary, the actual subtype of the formal is given by its nominal subtype.

Comment: Thanks! Here's some more rep, it looks like you desperately need it ;)

Comment: For such a nanny language that forbids anything remotely unsafe, allowing `out` parameters is like leaving a fully loaded assault rifle within easy reach.