# Ada out parameter

Tags: parameters, ada, out

I'm new to Ada.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185449/in-out-vs-out-in-ada), but mine is a little different:

```
    type A is record
        x : integer;
        y : integer;
    end record;

    procedure P1 is
      temp : A;
    begin
      temp.x := 100;
      P2(temp);
      if temp.x = 100 then
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("true");
      else
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("false");
      end if;
    end One;

    procedure P2 (arg1 : out A) is
    begin
      arg1.y := 200;
    end P2;
```

My question is with the "out" parameter in P2: will other parts of a composite type be undefined if P2 didn't explicitly set them. In other words, if P1 is called, would the output be definitely true or false? Or maybe ambiguous?

This [link](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-6.html) talks about "default initialization", but my example above doesn't have it explicitly (on purpose).

```
    Safety is preserved by ensuring that a subcomponent does not become
    "deinitialized" by being passed as an out parameter. If any subcomponent
    of a type passed by copy has default initialization, then the whole
    object is copied in at the start of the call so that the value of such a
    subcomponent is not lost as a result of a subprogram call during which
    no assignment is made to the subcomponent. But in practice records are
    usually passed by reference anyway.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quoted passage, [*§6.1.1 Out Parameters*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-6.html#1-1), may be easier to understand after reviewing [*§6.2 Formal Parameter Modes*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-6-2.html). For a parameter of type `A`, "it is unspecified whether the parameter is passed *by copy* or *by reference*." The implementation is free to choose. In either case, the `x` component of a value of type `A` is unchanged by `P2`. `P1` prints "true" because you have given the `x` component a value of `100` explicitly prior to calling `P2`. Absent initialization, default or otherwise, `temp.x` contains whatever bits were in memory when making room for `temp`, typically by adjusting a stack pointer.

As an exercise, try omitting the initialization and examining the value:

```
--temp.x := 100;
P2(temp);
if temp.x = 100 then
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("true");
else
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("false");
end if;
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(temp.x'Img & temp.y'Img);
```

On my implementation, the predicate fails and `temp.x` contains garbage.

```
false
 1934820168 200
```

Using a [*default_expression*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-8.html) with the record components avoids the risk of overlooking the initialization.

```
type A is record
    x : integer := 0;
    y : integer := 0;
end record;
```

> If it is compiler dependent, then is using `in out` the only sure way to make sure it works.

Absent default initialization, yes. As noted in [*§6.1 Parameter and Result Mechanism*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-6.html#1), "In Ada 95 it is not [erroneous](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-1-1-5.html) to depend on the parameter passing mechanism (*by-reference* versus *by-copy*) for those types that allow both, though it is **nonportable**." Because `arg1` in `P2` is an `out` parameter that *may* be passed *by copy*—and it is neither an access type nor a composite type with discriminants nor a type having an implicit initial value—[*§6.4.1 Parameter Associations*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-6-4-1.html) makes clear that "the formal parameter is **uninitialized**." In contrast, for an `in out` parameter, "the value of the actual parameter is…**assigned** to the formal."

Comment: I’m not sure whether this is compiler-specific behaviour? Would a compiler which was able to pass by copy behave the same? I would try not to risk it!

Comment: Thank you @trashgod. If it is compiler dependent, then is using "in out" the only sure way to make sure it works (if you are not sure the record passed in has default initialization):  
  
    `procedure P2 (arg1 : in out A) is`
    `begin`  
        `arg1.y := 200;`  
    `end P2;`

Comment: @TNguyen: I've elaborated above.